# Javascript variable scope in object literal

Tags: javascript, variables, object-literal

a newbie question.. Here's my code:

```
let result = (...ohStr) => {
    let res = []; // edited (before res = [])
    for (const Str of ohStr){
        if(/oh{3,6} no/.test(Str)){
            res.push({Str:true});
        }
        else{
            res.push({Str:false});
        }
    }
        return res;
}

console.log(result("ohhh no","ohhhh no","ohhhhh no","oh no","ohh no"));
```

The question is why *the res* array is created like this:

```
[ { Str: true },
  { Str: true },
  { Str: true },
  { Str: false },
  { Str: false } ]
```

instead adding the Str value every iteration in for loop? and how I overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you want just a singular result, or a mapped result? `res = []` (which should be `let res = []` by the way) indicates an array result is desired. Are you hoping for `{"ohhh no": true}` instead?

Comment: Try pushing { [Str]: true }

Comment: Do you want only values like `true` or `false` in an array

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: singular result, btw i'll edit ```res = []``` to ```let res = []```

Comment: If you want a single result you can replace `res.push({Str:X});` to `res['Str] = X` where 'X' refers to any value true/false

Comment: thanks, my bad didnt do a further search topics...

Comment: Fixed it up a bunch [here](https://gist.github.com/tadman/91c320b5b8930798549376587cd7c78d). Someone slammed the question closed before I could add an answer.

Comment: @tadman It's a duplicate, are we supposed to answer those instead?

Comment: @ikhvjs It's not filtering in this form, it's mapping.

Comment: @ChrisG There's multiple problems in this question that need addressing. That's just the biggest one.